# Column is empty then error as Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Using VB.Net

If the grid cell value is empty, i am getting error as "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid"

Code (gridview_CellLeave)

```
Dim z1, z2, z3, z4 As Int32


        If grvList.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value <> "" Then
            z1 = grvList.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
        End If
        If grvList.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value <> "" Then
            z2 = grvList.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value
        End If
        If grvList.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value <> "" Then
            z3 = grvList.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value
        End If
        If grvList.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value <> "" Then
            z4 = grvList.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value
        End If
```

How to solve this error.

Need Vb.net code Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as suggested, use the TryParse method, thus avoiding also use the try / catch, because that method already handles any format errors.

```
 Dim z1, z2, z3, z4 As Int32

    If Integer.TryParse(grvList.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value, z1) Then
        'your code here
    End If

     Dim z1, z2, z3, z4 As Double

    If Double.TryParse(grvList.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value, z1) Then
        'your code here
    End If
```

and so all other

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TryParse` method.

```
Integer.TryParse(text,intVar)
Double.TryParse(text,doubleVar)
```